# Cat eye infection

Tags: cats, health, eye-disease

The mother cat gave birth to three kittens in our backyard. After the first month, I noticed one of the kittens' eyes has some "rheum" and is semi closed. I thought maybe it'd go away by it self (bad mistake)...

In the second month, when they started walking outside, both the kitten's eyes were completely closed, so I took him to a vet.

*(a side note about the vet; in the small city where I'm living, there is not an "experienced" vet which is an expert in cats or dogs. They just do cows and sheep vaccinations etc...)*

The vet injected a dose of an antibiotic and another dose of dexamethasone and prescribed:

1. Si fixim syrup 5ml a day
2. Prednisolone 5mg 1/10 every 12 hours
3. Chloramphenicol 0.5% one drop every 12 hours
4. Sterile eye drop every 8 hours
5. B-complex vitamin syrup 5ml a day

It's the third day that I'm using those medications for this poor kitty and even though the "rheum" is reduced, his eyes are still closed (until I clean them using eye-drops) and still have inflammation. His eyes outside the corners are PURE RED (not visible in the picture,) and when I use eye drops, the kitten is in pain... :(

Other than that he's playful and eats well.

I changed their "nest" and cleaned the whole backyard so they can live in an clean environment. Don't know what else to do to cure him--he's too young to become blind!

Has the vet prescribed the correct medications? If yes, why isn't the inflammation going away?

If the medications isn't the right one, and you're a vet, please suggest another prescriptions. I can't afford to take him to another vet. it's pretty expensive in here...

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it is best to take the cat to another vet if the treatment does not work in 3-4 days.

The medications given against an allergic reaction are dexamethasone and prednisolone, and these have an anti-inflammatory effect too, to reduce the swelling.

Si-Fixim is a broad spectrum antibiotic, so it will help if there is an infection going on.

Chloramphenicol is antibacterial and the B-vitamins are probably not very important as a treatment for the cat.

The treatment your local vet has given the cat is a good one. He has treated everything he can think of (it might be a little over the top).

Comment: so i shouldn't be worried about? maybe it go away in next 3 days or something?

Comment: 3-4 days is from the start of medication,be sure the cat have water at all times.